# Disambiguating unquoted string literals and identifiers

Tags: antlr4

I've inherited a file format that looks little like the following.

```
someBlock {
  Widget "Widget 1" "Some long optional description" // Quoted multi-word name
  widget2 = Widget Widget2 "Another long optional description" // Unquoted single-word name
  widget3 = Widget Three // No description
  dongle1 = Dongle foo
  dongle2 = Dongle "bar baz" "some long optional description"
  Gadget hammer
}
```

Widgets have a name and an optional description.

One quirk of the grammar is that string literals only need to be in quotes if they're multi-word (i.e. contain spaces), so `"Widget1"` is the same as `Widget1`.

Widgets can optionally be assigned to an identifier (e.g. `widget2`, `widget3`), or they can be anonymous as in the case of the first Widget above.

The fact that unquoted string literals exist and that there is no keyword (e.g. `let`, `var`) defined to declare a variable I'm struggling with how to model this in the grammar so that the parser does as much of the work as possible. Is there something I could do to say "anything before an `=` is an identifier (as opposed to a string literal)?

Hoping someone can give me a steer. Thanks a million!

Comment: How does this language distinguish between a quoted identifier and a string for the description? Is there a positional requirement, i.e.  does it depend on where the string literal appears?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't distinguish between them, Mike. Unquoted string literals can appear anywhere a quoted string literal can (obviously with the limitation that if unquoted, they can only be a single word).

The ambiguity of the language doesn't make writing parsers easy, but I'm reminded of something I read once that the job of a language designer is to make the life of the user easy, not the parser developed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String`s and `ID`s are almost certainly going to be tokens (produced by the Lexer).

If *ALL* widgets were named, you could use a Lexer mode to switch into an "after = but before comment or nl" mode, and introduce new new Lexer rules (and use the `type()` Lexer action to assign an already defined token type.

Unfortunately, Lexers don't really do any look ahead, so there is no way for it to day an "anything before ..." type of Lexer rule.

This grammar seems to give a valid parse tree of your input (with some assumptions I'm having to make re: interpreting your input):

```
grammar FF
    ;

block: ID '{' widget* '}' EOF;

widget: (ID '=')? WIDGET name description? COMMENT?;

name: ID | STRING;

description: STRING;

WIDGET:  'Widget';
ID:      [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+;
STRING:  '"' ~["]*? '"';
COMMENT: '//' ~[\n]*;
WS:      [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

Resulting parse tree:

[image]

Comment: > Lexer mode to switch into an "after = but before comment or nl" mode


It's slightly more complicated than I outlined. There are things other than Widgets. There are also Gadgets and Dongles that have the same quirks.

Comment: I've updated the original sample to include Gadgets and Dongles. I think I'm going to need to go with your switch mode after '=' suggestion and consume up to NL.

Comment: Looking at this again, you've put me on the right track with "name: ID | STRING". Thanks a million!